# Nested For Loop With Filesystem in Batch

Tags: batch-file, for-loop

I'm having trouble searching the filesystem for the lowermost filename in the file hierarchy. I get the parent folders but not the files within those folders.

With the network file \ExampleServer\ExampleFile being search with the directory parentFolder1\childFolder1\childFile1.txt in it, my output looks like:

```
filedrive=\\
filepath= \\ExampleServer\ExampleFile\\parentFolder1\childFolder1\
filename = childFolder1
fileextension =
```

but I would like my output to be:

```
filedrive=\\
filepath= \\ExampleServer\ExampleFile\\parentFolder1\childFolder1\childFile1.txt
filename = childFile1.txt
fileextension = .txt
```

My code so far is below.

```
@echo off

:userInput
REM ask user for network share and file that they would like to search
echo What is the network share you would like to search (non-case sensitive)?
set /p networkShareName=Enter The Value:%=%
echo What is the file within the network share that you would like to search(non-case sensitive)?
set /p fileName=Enter The Value:%=%

REM check if network path is available
IF exist \\%networkShareName%\%fileName%\ (
    echo File found
    for /F "tokens=*" %%i in (C:\Users\user\Desktop\filenames.txt) do 
        for /r \\%networkShareName%\%fileName%\ %%G IN (.) DO 
            ECHO filedrive=%%~dG & 
            ECHO filepath=%%~pG & 
            ECHO filename=%%~nG & 
            ECHO fileextension=%%~xG & 
            ECHO %~$PATH:G
)
IF NOT exist \\%networkShareName%\%fileName%\ (
    echo File not found
    GOTO:userInput
)
```

I've tried for files but I can't use the with `UNC` resources. Also, I've tried `pushd` and `popd` to work around this, but I don't have permissions on my pc to map drive letters of network drive, so I can't do that at this moment.

Comment: @wOxxOm I was afraid I didn't explain it well enough. I'll make revisions.

Comment: Try `... for /r \\%networkShareName%\%fileName%\ %%G IN (*) DO echo %%i & Echo ... `: note `in (*)` instead of `in (.)`. Double percent sign in `ECHO %~$PATH:G`

Comment: @JosefZ That answered my question!